Xiomi Redmi camera photos in 200MP sometimes show a "grid" artifact
My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 13 Pro+, and when I take pictures in 200 megapixels mode, sometimes I see a grid (you can see it around the center of the image below).
What I've noticed is this happens during summer (or when the weather is relatively hot), when I take 200MP images, and when I take several quickly - then one in every three pictures might have such a grid.
Because of that, I was wondering if it's a CPU overheating issue - maybe 200MP requires too much processing power so if it's hot it just doesn't process it all the way.
Does anyone know if this is a known issue in Xiaomi Redmi Note 13 Pro+, or does it happen for just my phone?

Edit: According to gsmarena, the sensor is indeed 200MP:

The Redmi Note 13 Pro+ 5G has a trio of cameras on the back, with the primary one being one of the key marketed features of this device. We have a 200MP Samsung ISOCELL HP3 sensor here along with a 23mm equivalent 7P lens, f1.65 aperture, and OIS. The sensor operates in a 16 to 1 mode by default and produces 12.5MP images. It can, however, capture native 200MP images as well as use center crops to produce lossless 2x and 4x images.


That sure looks like a composite grid to me...
My guess is that the camera doesn't actually have a 200MP sensor, but rather combines multiple images to generate that. Much like the Xiaomi Mi 10 renders 108MP with a 27MP sensor; while being marketed as having a "108MP main camera."
That said, I couldn't find exact/true specs for your camera/sensor with a quick search.
I read that the first image taken on your Xiaomi is in some kind of "quick" mode and it may render a better image for the second one taken; although the second image taxes the phone much harder. It's possible the lines are due to de-binning the 16:1 default 12.5 MP images.
It's also possible that the artifacts are due to some form of AI detail addition/enhancement as there is no way the camera/lens can resolve an actual 200MP of detail on a 1/1.4 sensor (0.56um)... even blue wavelengths resolve to 1um through an optically perfect f/1.0 lens (which doesn't even exist).

For the camera specs, perhaps GSM Arena may help?

The sensor should be 200 MP - it's ISOCELL HP3 - I edited to question to add details

The information in the edit seems to suggest an answer - it can capture at 200MP, but isn't really intended to do that (it's not the default). It could be the processing - in particular pixel binning (or what happens when you don't do pixel binning) - that's introducing artefacts.
Samsung's ISOCELL HP3 page (the section on low light) is also written in a way that suggests the sensor really comes into its own when simulating a 50MP or 12.5MP camera, specifically :

The ISOCELL HP3 also provides an ultimate low-light experience, with
the Tetra2pixel technology that combines four pixels into one to
transform the 0.56μm 200MP sensor into a 1.12μm 50MP sensor, or a
12.5MP sensor with 2.24μm-pixels by combining 16 pixels into one.

There's more discussion on multipixel sensors on this question.
It looks like the issue is that a 200MP sensor and a 200MP image are not as closely related as the words might suggest.
